# Combining or and negation in Java regex?

Tags: java, regex, string-matching, regex-negation

I am trying to combine the usage of "not" and "or" to produce a set of regex matching like so:

```
"blah" matching "zero or more of" : "not h"         or  "any in b,l,a" = false 
"blah" matching "zero or more of" : "any in b,l,a"  or  "not h"        = false  
"blah" matching "zero or more of" : "not n"         or  "any in b,l,a" = true  
"blah" matching "zero or more of" : "any in b,l,a"  or  "not n"        = true
```

I have tried the following regular expressions, but they don't seem to achieve what I am looking for. I've also included my interpretation of the regexes:

```
//first set attempt - turns out to be any of the characters within?
System.out.println("blah".matches("[bla|^h]*"));    //true
System.out.println("blah".matches("[^h|bla]*"));    //false
System.out.println("blah".matches("[bla|^n]*"));    //false
System.out.println("blah".matches("[^n|bla]*"));    //false
//second set attempt - turns out to be the literal text
System.out.println("blah".matches("(bla|^h)*"));    //false
System.out.println("blah".matches("(^h|bla)*"));    //false
System.out.println("blah".matches("(bla|^n)*"));    //false
System.out.println("blah".matches("(^n|bla)*"));    //false
//third set attempt - almost gives the right results, but it's still off somehow
System.out.println("blah".matches("[bla]|[^h]*"));  //false
System.out.println("blah".matches("[^h]|[bla]*"));  //false
System.out.println("blah".matches("[bla]|[^n]*"));  //true
System.out.println("blah".matches("[^n]|[bla]*"));  //false
```

So, in the end, I am wondering about the following:

1. Are my interpretations of the above regexes correct?
2. What is a group of four Java regex that match my specification?
3. <sup><sub>(Optional) Am I making other mistakes in my regex?</sub></sup>

With regards to fuzzy requirements, I'd just like to make the following point:
The regex subdivisions could have been something like ("not [abc]" or "bc")* which would match any string that is like `bcbc...` or `...` where characters are not `a`s, `b`s, or `c`s. I just chose "blah" as a general example, like "foo" or "bar".

Comment: It's not negative lookahead, because that is avoiding future elements. I just want to check the current element for matching like this.

Comment: @Turing85 it is negation, but in character set context of `[]`

Comment: ***FYI:*** `[^h|bla]` means "not an `h`, `|`, `b`, `l`, or `a`", however `^` only has special meaning in first position, so `[bla|^h]` means "a `b`, `l`, `a`, `|`, `^`, or `h`".

Comment: @Andreas Oh, that sounds problematic. I'll keep that in mind, in future :)

Comment: An overall comment: your current semantics for the regex say: if a character is neither `'b'`, `'l'` or`'a'`, then it must not be a `'h'`. In other words: a character can be anything, except an `h`. Is this really what you want?

Comment: @Turing85 It's more of a general example than a precise one, so that I can get an understanding of how to combine the two :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first 2 conditions you may use:

```
^(?:[bla]|[^h])*$
```

And next 2 you may use:

```
^(?:[bla]|[^n])*$
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `[bla]`: Match one of `b or l or a`:
  - `|`: OR
  - `[^h]`: Match any char that is not `h`
- `)*`: End non-capture group, match 0 or more of this group
- `$`: End
  [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mxKyPP/1)

Note that for `.matches`, anchors are implicit so you can omit `^` and `$`.

Comment: `[^h]` allows b's, l's and a's and anything else other than h's, so `[bla]|[^h]` is quite redundant and certainly not what you want

Comment: You're right, OP's requirements itself are fuzzy.

Comment: @Avi: You will need to clarify requirement because **not h** satisfies `[bla` so there is no need of any OR condition there.

Comment: This should be correct according to what I required. Non-capturing group is maybe not necessary, but that's ok.

Comment: ok glad to know but just keep in mind that just `^[^h]*$` will also work for you.

Answer (score 1):

To combine your criteria, use separate, alternative character sets [] in eg non capturing group, so

`"[bla|^h]*"` would be

`(?:[bla]*|[^h]*)+`

which is something like "at least one occurence of (b,l,a or not h)"

Just keep im mind that matching with `*` means "may occure" (technically zero or more)

Comment: `[^h]` allows b's, l's and a's and anything else other than h's, so `[bla]|[^h]` is quite redundant and certainly not what you want

Comment: @Andreas you want me to correct OP's the requirement?

Comment: @Antoniossss Your regex doesn't compile. What is the ? doing alone at the beginning?

Comment: its missing (?`:`

Comment: @Antoniossss ah, non-capturing? -1 removed

Comment: @Antoniossss well.. why not [edit] your answer then?

Comment: Yep already done

Answer (score 1):

"not h" can be written in multiple ways:

```
(?!.*h.*)
[^h]*
```

"any in b,l,a"<sup>1</sup>:

```
[bla]*
```

<sup>1) Assuming you mean "only one of b,l,a", otherwise all 4 examples in the question would be `true`</sup>

Combining using `or` would then be:

```
[^h]*|[bla]*
```

which means "must be a string not containing `h`, or must be a string consisting of only `b`, `l`, and `a` characters.

In this case, the order of the `|` makes no difference, so `[^h]*|[bla]*` and `[bla]*|[^h]*` works the same.

```
System.out.println("blah".matches("[bla]*|[^h]*"));  //false
System.out.println("blah".matches("[^h]*|[bla]*"));  //false
System.out.println("blah".matches("[bla]*|[^n]*"));  //true
System.out.println("blah".matches("[^n]*|[bla]*"));  //true
```